# Copy from AWS S3 to Snowflake is taking more time than usual

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we are trying to load data from AWS S3 to Snowflake stage using copy command and it is taking more time than usual, and the size of the file is 3 GB(this size is including all the files existing in the folder). below is the copy command.

`

```
create or replace stage mystage
url='s3://s3bucket/folder'
storage_integration=myparquet
file_format = (type = parquet) PURGE=TRUE;

copy into mytable
from @mystage/mytable/
pattern='.*.[.]parquet'
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE TRUNCATECOLUMNS = TRUE force=TRUE;`
```

please let me know , how we can load this quickly.
Thanks,

Comment: Define what is **usual** and what is **more time**!

Comment: the same size of file set is loading with in 5 mins but the other one is taking more than 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You said, it's taking more time than usual. In this case, I assume you use the same command on the same sized warehouse for the similar amount of data. In this case, it's not possible to diagnose the issue by just looking at your SQL command. If you haven't checked yet, you may compare your good run to the current (bad) run to see if anything is different now.

If I were you, I would submit a support ticket to Snowflake Support. They can investigate the query logs, execution statistics and provide you some insights to help you improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks Atil for your suggestion. i have aborted the copy command as it was taking more than 1 hour. as you suggested i will submit support ticket.